# * [blocked] --> Synonym of [?-ban]

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request

[blocked](/questions/tagged/blocked) --> [tag:?-ban]

No usage guidance nor tag wiki, no clear meaning (we have various tags like [ip-ban] [post-ban] [review-ban] etc.), ambiguous. Only serves as a signpost.

Can we make [blocked](/questions/tagged/blocked) a synonym of [something-ban](/questions/tagged/something-ban) (possibly [post-ban])?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New users who get blocked for whatever reason will use it as a search term rather than those other options above, that are more useful for higher rep folks.

I'd suggest it should remain, or at the very most, I guess it could be a synonym, rather than being blocked.